# Interchanging the columns in HTML page based on pre-selected configuration in database

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts

I have an application where I need to interchange columns based on the configuration done in some other section. Like for example I have a Listing screen where we show all the data related to a particular case. And we have another section called Admin>>Customization where we allow user to select column ordering. Now once the column ordering is set in the Customization section, all columns should be displayed in Listing screen according to that order

I am trying with different things but none are giving accurate result.

The application is completely based on Struts

Please help

Thanks 
Dilip H P

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: get properties by name and not by their index.

Comment: [inline]
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {jQuery.each($("table tr"), function() { 
        $(this).children(":eq(7)").after($(this).children(":eq(5)"));
    });
});
</script>
[/inlin
Above script I got after a lot of search through Google. But this has to be connected to database and. In the back end we have a table that stores the order of each column. 
Table structure is 

COLUMN_NAME  COLUMN_ORDER
MessageNumber  4 
RepIdentifier  1
Receiver       2

Like this. But I am not sure on how to extract this data and get it to JQuery and use it rearrange the columns in HTML page

Answer (score 0):

What is the approach that you are using to display the customization screen?
You could use the list to store the order of the column selection, and then can get the properties by name to display the results in the required manner.

Comment: In customization screen I have some dropdowns which has the column names, to be displayed, like Column 1: 'Message Number', 'Report Identifier', 'Receiver'...etc.., Like this I have 4 more drop down having the same values.
Once these values are set and saved into the database, I need to take this data and use it to design the HTML page for the front end where cases are displayed Having these columns. If 'Report Identifier' is column

Comment: If 'Message Number' is column 4 'Report Identifier' is column '7' and in the customization if the use sets out the order as 'Message Number' - 7 and 'Report Identifier' as 4 then in the front the same should happen.
This is same as SharePoint where there is an option to rearrange the columns according to how the user wishes